# break tie between k-means cluster

Tags: statistics, k-means, data-analysis

I have dataset on which I applied k-means and there are two clusters but distance from a particular point (x,y) to both cluster is same ,then in which cluster the point will go. please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In k-means clustering you're minimising the sum of (pairwise) squared distances between points within one cluster, not of individual points to cluster centres. When working with numerical data I would imagine that ties are not very common. Can you post sample data and code to illustrate?

Comment: you mean . it will never  possible that  a data point will common to both cluster?

Comment: No, that's not what I'm saying. I'm saying that when working with numerical data, exact ties (i.e. equal squared distances between points within clusters when assigning a point to two different clusters) will be rare. I'm curious to see an example, which is why I asked for sample data and code.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Actually I don't have data point but I asked, what if this condition comes in future, because I read about math behind k-means  then I thought it may be the case .

Comment: I see. Perhaps take a look at [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/46006/equal-euclidean-distance-of-a-single-data-point-to-all-the-cluster-centers) for some further details. Equal Euclidean distances of a single point to two cluster centres don't necessarily have to relate to equal pairwise squared distances between points within clusters. As I said, I imagine the latter to occur very rarely, but I don't have a practical (counter-)example to demonstrate. It might be interesting to generate some sample data and try to construct such a "clustering with ties" example yourself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180651/discussion-between-mks-and-maurits-evers).

Answer (score 4):

### tldr;

In the case of ties, k-means clustering will randomly assign the ambiguous point to a cluster. (This is based on R's implementation of k-means clustering `kmeans`.)

---

### A specific example based on the `iris` data in R

1. Let's start by loading necessary R libraries

   ```
   library(broom)
   library(tidyverse)
   ```
2. For this example, we will use the `Petal.Length` and `Petal.Width` measurements from the `iris` dataset, and for simplicity exclude the "virginica" measurements so that the "setosa" and "versicolor" measurements form our two groups.

   ```
   df <- iris %>%
       filter(Species != "virginica") %>%
       select(starts_with("Petal"), Species)
   ```
3. We now use k-means clustering with k = 2, and assign a cluster label to every (`Petal.Length`, `Petal.Width`) measurement; since the assignment of which group is "1" and which group is "2" is random, we use a fixed seed for reproducibility.

   ```
   set.seed(2018)
   kcl <- kmeans(df %>% select(-Species), 2)
   df <- augment(kcl, df)
   ```
4. We show a scatterplot of `Petal.Length` vs. `Petal.Width`; the known `Species` labels are shown by the different colours and the inferred cluster association by the different symbols.

   ```
   ggplot(df, aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width, colour = Species)) +
       geom_point(aes(shape = .cluster), size = 3)
   ```

   [image]
5. Let's manually calculate the within-cluster sum of squared pairwise distances; since we'll be needing this later as well, we'll create a function `calculate_d`.

   ```
   calculate_d <- function(df) {
       df %>%
           select(.cluster, Petal.Length, Petal.Width) %>%
           group_by(.cluster) %>%
           nest() %>%
           mutate(dist = map_dbl(data, ~sum(as.matrix(dist(.x)^2)) / (2 * nrow(.x)))) %>%
           pull(dist)
   }

   calculate_d(df)
   #[1]  2.0220 12.7362
   ```

   Notice how the distances are identical to the within-cluster sum of squares (WCSS)

   ```
   kcl$withinss
   #[1]  2.0220 12.7362
   ```
6. Now let's add a new measurement that has the same Euclidean distance from both cluster centers: to do so, we choose the point that lies exactly half-way between both cluster centers if you connect them by a straight line. All we need then is a bit of basic trigonometry to construct that point:

   ```
   z <- kcl$centers[2, ] - kcl$center[1, ]
   theta <- atan(z[2] / z[1])

   dy <- sin(theta) * dist(kcl$centers) / 2
   dx <- cos(theta) * dist(kcl$centers) / 2

   x <- as.numeric(kcl$centers[1, 1] + dx)
   y <- as.numeric(kcl$centers[1, 2] + dy)
   ```

   We store our new point together with the 2 cluster centers in a new `data.frame`. The first two rows give the position of cluster "1" and "2", and the third row contains our new point.

   ```
   df2 <- bind_rows(as.data.frame(kcl$centers), c(Petal.Length = x, Petal.Width = y))
   ```

   Let's show the new point together with the cluster centers on top of our (`Petal.Length`, `Petal.Width`) measurements.

   ```
   df2 <- bind_rows(as.data.frame(kcl$centers), c(Petal.Length = x, Petal.Width = y))
   ggplot(df, aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width)) +
       geom_point(aes(colour = Species, shape = .cluster), size = 3) +
       geom_point(data = df2, aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width), size = 4)
   ```

   [image]

   We confirm that the squared Euclidean distance between the new point and each cluster center is indeed the same; to do so we calculate the pairwise distances of our new point "3" to the cluster centres "1" and "2":

   ```
   as.matrix(dist(df2))[, 3]
   #     1      2      3
   #1.4996 1.4996 0.0000
   ```
7. Now let's add our new point to the (`Petal.Length`,`Petal.Width`) measurements, and calculate the within cluster sum of squared pairwise distances, first with assigning our new point to cluster "1" and then with assigning our new point to cluster "2".

   ```
   # Add new point and assign to cluster "1"
   df.1 <- df %>%
       bind_rows(cbind.data.frame(
           Petal.Length = x,
           Petal.Width = y,
           Species = factor("setosa", levels = levels(df$Species)),
           .cluster = factor(1, levels = 1:2)))
   calculate_d(df.1)
   #[1]  4.226707 12.736200

   # Add new point and assign to cluster "2"
   df.2 <- df %>%
       bind_rows(cbind.data.frame(
           Petal.Length = x,
           Petal.Width = y,
           Species = factor("versicolor", levels = levels(df$Species)),
           .cluster = factor(2, levels = 1:2)))
   calculate_d(df.2)
   #[1]  2.02200 14.94091
   ```

   Notice how the within-cluster squared pairwise distances are different even though the new point has exactly the same distances from either cluster centre. However notice also, how the *sum* of the within-cluster squared pairwise distances is the same!

   ```
   sum(calculate_d(df.1))
   #[1] 16.96291

   sum(calculate_d(df.2))
   #[1] 16.96291

   identical(sum(calculate_d(df.2)), sum(calculate_d(df.1)))
   # [1] TRUE
   ```
8. To show that `kmeans` assigns the new point at random to either cluster we repeatedly cluster the data. To do so, we define a convenience function that returns the corresponding `Species` of the new point following k-means clustering.

   ```
   kmeans_cluster_data <- function(df) {
       kcl <- kmeans(df %>% select(-Species), 2)
       df <- augment(kcl, df)
       map_cluster_to_Species <- df[1:(nrow(df) - 1), ] %>%
           count(Species, .cluster) %>%
           split(., .$.cluster)
       map_cluster_to_Species[[
           df[nrow(df), ] %>%
               pull(.cluster) %>%
               as.character()]]$Species %>% as.character()
   }
   ```

   We now repeatedly cluster the same data 100 times.

   ```
   bind_cols(
       Iteration = 1:100,
       Species = map_chr(1:100, ~kmeans_cluster_data(df.1 %>% select(-.cluster)))) %>%
   ggplot(aes(Iteration, Species, group = 1)) +
       geom_line() +
       labs(title = "Assignment of new point to group")
   ```

   [image]

   Notice how the new point gets assigned to either `Species` group at random.

Comment: @mks I've updated my post with a (somewhat lengthy but hopefully explicit) example.

Comment: @mks You're very welcome, this was an interesting little project. I'd still say that ties will be quite rare, but it's good to know what happens *if* they occur. PS. Please consider closing the question by setting the green check mark next to answer. That way you help future readers identify answers to similar problems, and keep SO tidy.